# Vertical RadioButtonBar in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I want to make a vertical `RadioButtonBar` in `Manipulate`. So far I only have a workaround that looks like this:

```
Manipulate[
  Which[
  sel == 0,
  Text["one"],

  sel == 1,
  Text["two"],

  sel == 2,
  Text["three"]
  ],
  Control[{{sel, 0, ""}, {0 -> "one"}, ControlType -> RadioButton}],
  Control[{{sel, 1, ""}, {1 -> "two"}, ControlType -> RadioButton}],
  Control[{{sel, 2, ""}, {2 -> "three"}, 
  ControlType -> RadioButton}],

  ControlPlacement -> Left
  ]
```

Is there any way not to have a line for each of the radiobuttons? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `RadioButtonBar` if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Switch[sel,
  0, Text["one"],
  1, Text["two"],
  2, Text["three"]], {{sel, 0, ""}, {0 -> "one", 1 -> "two", 
   2 -> "three"}, ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
  Appearance -> "Vertical"}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. - I did check for the 'Appearance -> "Vertical"' option, but obviously must have done something wrong. I'm glad it's working now.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `Dynamic` function as follows:

```
DynamicModule[{sel}, 
 Panel[Row[{RadioButtonBar[
     Dynamic[sel], {1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two", 3 -> "Three"}, 
     Appearance -> "Vertical"], 
    Panel[Dynamic[
      Which[sel == 1, Text["one"], sel == 2, Text["two"], sel == 3, 
       Text["three"]]], ImageSize -> {50, 50}]}]]]
```

This avoids to to have a line for each of the radiobuttons.

Comment: I know DynamicModule is much more flexible, but unfortunately I did not have time yet to familiarise myself with it. - But thanks a lot for the suggestion! I'll keep the code and come back to it later.